# Changing subdir in new_post in blogdown R package

Tags: r, blogdown

I want to change **subdir**  to **content/myaseen208** for `new_post` **R** function from `blogdown`. However, my following code is producing **ASD.md** in **content** rather than in **content/myaseen208**. Any thoughts, please.

```
# Creating New Post
library(blogdown) 
options(
  blogdown.author = "Muhammad Yaseen"
  , blogdown.subdir = "myaseen208"
  , blogdown.ext    = ".md"
)

# options()$blogdown.subdir

blogdown::new_post(
    title      = "ASD"
  , kind       = "default"
  , open       = interactive()
  , author     = "Muhammad Yaseen"
  , categories = c("Statistics", "R")
  , tags       = NULL
  , date       = Sys.Date()
  , file       = "ASD.md"
  , slug       = NULL
  , title_case = getOption("blogdown.title_case")
  #  , subdir     = getOption("blogdown.subdir", "myaseen208")
  , ext        = getOption("blogdown.ext", ".md")
)
```

My `sessionInfo()` is

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
  [1] blogdown_0.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] compiler_3.4.4 tools_3.4.4    yaml_2.1.18    xfun_0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have provided the `file` argument to `blogdown::new_post()`. When it is provided, `new_post()` will respect your choice, and assume it is exactly the path you want. In your case, you either leave out `file` (let `new_post()` generate a path for you), or provide the full path, e.g., `file = 'myaseen208/ASD.md'`.

Comment: Thanks @YihuiXie for your answer and especially for **blogdown**.